# Changing the date format in orchard cms

Tags: .net, orchardcms

I'm trying to style the blog page and have added a date field, but the date always displays as mm/dd/yyyy, but I would like it to be displayed as day month(text) year. Is there a way to change this somehow?

Here is the code for the alternate template I'm using:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

@{
    string name = Model.ContentField.DisplayName;
}

<div class="date_tag">
<p class="date-time-field date-time-field-@name.HtmlClassify()">    
    @if (Model.Model.ShowDate) 
    { <text>@Model.Model.Date</text> } 
    @if (Model.Model.ShowTime)
    { <text>@Model.Model.Time</text> }
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The shape itself exposes the two strings, but the field contains the value, and the field can be accessed from the shape.

```
@Model.ContentField.DateTime
```

For reference: http://sebastienros.github.io/CheatSheet/

The DateTime field is the only field to add more information to the shape. So it's not missing anything, it just adds information to the shape.

To display the date correctly and in the correct timezone you need to use DateTime  shape helper like this:

```
@Display.DateTime(DateTimeUtc: Model.ContentField.DateTime, CustomFormat: T("d MM yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `@Model.Model.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")`?

Comment: yeah, I already tried that and it returned this error: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Are you using a DateTimeField? Because then it should be Model.Model.DateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"). Your template looks like you're really using two text fields that you called Date and Time.

Comment: it is a Date Time Field, but when I used the above code it threw another error: 'Orchard.Fields.ViewModels.DateTimeFieldViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'DateTime'. I'm not sure if this alternate template is right or not; I'm new to both Orchard and .net, but I just used the design module to generate the alternate template called Fields.DateTime-BlogPost.cshtml.

Comment: Oh, well, yes, that's a bug. the date time field should expose the DateTime value and it doesn't. Instead, it exposes two useless string properties. Good catch. Please file a bug and I'll commit the patch myself...

Comment: I've added this as a work item to Orchard - https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19810